# Cannot create or compile win32 projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, and 2017 installed on my windows pc.
All version have the C++ components installed.
When I try to build a win32 project in vs2015, I get the error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And If I try to create a new win32 project via the new project wizard, I can select the Win32 project types, but when I click OK, the wizard just reopens, with no error message.

[image: wizard]

This only occurs with vs2015. I have tried repairing the installation, and re-installing 2015, but no luck. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this: Build/Configuration Manager/Plataform/New/X86

Answer (score 0):

The basic gist of this, is that you have to install your vs versions in chronological order. 
If you fail to do this, for example, installing vs2015 first, certain tools or run-times will not be installed later, as installers for c++ runtimes are version number sensitive.

I had to uninstall all versions, and all c++ run times, then start again to solve the issue.